# Excel SUM of SUMIF/SUMIFS with dynamic multiple criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, sumifs, multiple-conditions

I need to pass a multiple criteria list (a constant array) via cell reference rather than hard-typing it into my formula.
So, instead of this:
`=SUM(SUMIFS(sum_range,criteria_range,{"red","blue"}))`
But I would need to use this:
`=SUM(SUMIFS(sum_range,criteria_range,$A1))` where $A1 is `{"red","blue"}`

I understand that one can use a range of cells to pass an array but I really need my condition to come from a single cell.
It seems that passing a constant array via cell reference only passes the first element to the formula (i.e. only "red" is used as a condition) and all the working examples I could find of this ([here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/11/12/excel-sumifs-sumif-multiple-criteria/#sumifs-multiple-or) or [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/sumifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logichttps://exceljet.net/formula/sumifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic)) are hard-typing the condition into the formula.

Any luck anybody ?

EDIT: I should add that my data set includes blank rows so it is not contiguous and in general, I'm looking for a not too convoluted solution that will work most of the time and with as little restrictions and caveats as possible.

Comment: So what formula do you use that works?  The actual formula not pseudo formula.

Comment: `=SUM(SUMIFS(W$12:W$448,$I$12:$I$448,$I474,$J$12:$J$448,$J474,$K$12:$K$448,{"red","blue"}))` is where I am at. This works on non-contiguous data.

Comment: Then changing to SUMPRODUCT and replacing the array with my formula will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With cell A1 containing `{"red","blue"}`  I then setup a named range `Condition` to which I assigned `=EVALUATE($A1)` and now I can pass my condition like so:
`=SUM(SUMIFS(W$12:W$448,$I$12:$I$448,$I474,$J$12:$J$448,$J474,$K$12:$K$448,Condition))`

Answer (score 3):

Change the "Array" in A1 to a comma delineated list:

```
blue,purple
```

No quotes or `{}`

Change the SUM to SUMPRODUCT and use this as the criteria:

```
TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(INDEX(AAA:AAA,1):INDEX(AAA:AAA,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99))
```

The `$20` should be placed at the max number of choices possible.  I just used it here as a placeholder, it can be more without problem but not less or it will skip any more than that.

[image]

---

Based on the formula you provided.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(W$12:W$448,$I$12:$I$448,$I474,$J$12:$J$448,$J474,$K$12:$K$448,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(INDEX(AAA:AAA,1):INDEX(AAA:AAA,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99))))
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't see that coming! That's quite a smart formula (I'm still trying to decipher it). However, it does not work on non-contiguous data, which is my case. I should have mentioned that perhaps...

Comment: Yes always include all the information. Please edit you question to include all requirements.

Comment: @YeO see edit.  again remember to change A1 to `Red,Blue` no quotes and no `{}`.

Comment: Ok... it does work indeed. However, take out 1 cell in your example, say G7 and it's off completely: it gives 28 as a result.

Comment: @YeO see new edit.  so the end does matter.  now it will iterate only the number of times there is words.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! Would you mind explaining a little bit what's the trick in your formula? I'm happy that it works but I don't have a clue as to why...

Comment: It separates the "words" with 99 spaces, which gives us a big target to hit.  The MID grabs each piece as the `(ROW(INDEX(AAA:AAA,1):INDEX(AAA:AAA,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1` iterates.  So the INDEXes in this case resolve to ROW(AAA1:AAA2)` which returns an array of {1,2}.  So as it iterates the math in the mid starts the two "words" at positions 1 and 100 which with 99 spaces lands us in the spaces.  The trim removes the extra spaces and we are left with an array of `{"blue","purple"}`.

Comment: Ok! I think I understand now. I did not know ROW returned an array (nor that you could feed and array to MID...) I'm going to sleep smarter tonight. Thanks a bunch!