# Excel Sumifs with multiple arrays referenced on another cell

Tags: excel, formula

I have a formula that sums one column based on a criteria from another column. This formula works fine:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(sheet1!C:C,sheet1!A:A,{1, 7}))
```

However, i need to be able to use a cell reference which will contain the {1, 7}

So the formula will look like this:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(sheet1!C:C,sheet1!A:A,M2))
```

But this returns a zero, when evaluting the formula it pulls the contents from the cell but wraps it in "" which i think is where the issue is happening.

I've tried adding formula to remove the quotes, and trying to pull the contents differently, but still the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's because the {1,7} in the other cell is stored as a text value - I personally don't know a way to fix that exactly althought wouldn't be surprised if there's one out there. 
How did "{1, 7}" get to that other cell, is there a further-back stage you could go to or was it manually typed into Cell M2 like that?

Comment: It was manually typed in. Yea youre right about the text value, ive tried using numbervalue but doesnt work with the comma being there.

Comment: In my test just `SUMIFS(sheet1!C:C,sheet1!A:A,M2)` works fine (drop the `sum()` )

Comment: The sum i have to use i pull the sum from two different rows, one row has a number 1 on and another cell has number 7. Its not always going to be 1, 7, so its dynamic based on M2. I've tried your test and it pulls if i just have a single figure, but not if i have a 1 and 7

Comment: @HulkSmash93 in which case could you use two cells for the input? `=SUM(SUMIFS(sheet1!C:C,sheet1!A:A,{M2: M3}))`. I get why you're using the `SUM()` on the outside of it, cos it's  an array and would spill otherwise.

Comment: Its possible, i would have to use this to work:
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(sheet1!C:C,sheet1!A:A,M2: N2))
But id be limited on how many i can have then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way round this.

I created a named range called condition, and assigned `=Evaluate($M2)`.

Then I used this formula `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(sheet1!C:C,sheet1!A:A,Condition))`

This picks up all numbers used in M2, and works on all rows below with the Evaluate formula following.

Thank you to everyone that assisted with this.

This link helped aswell: [Excel SUM of SUMIF/SUMIFS with dynamic multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265408/excel-sum-of-sumif-sumifs-with-dynamic-multiple-criteria)